# Python extracting new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
  topic  student level 
    1      a       1     
    1      b       2     
    1      a       3     
    2      a       1     
    2      b       2     
    2      a       3     
    2      b       4     
    3      c       1     
    3      b       2     
    3      c       3     
    3      a       4     
    3      b       5
```

It contains a column level that specifies who started the topic and who replied to it. If a level is 1, it means that a student started the topic. If a level is 2, it means that a student replied to student who started the topic. If a level is 3, it means that a student replied to student at level 2 and on and on.

I would like to extract a new dataframe that should present a communication between students through the topic. It should contain three columns: "student source", "student destination" and "reply count". Reply count is a number of times in which Student Destination "directly" replied to Student Source.

I should get something like:

```
   st_source st_dest reply_count
        a        b       4
        a        c       0
        b        a       2
        b        c       1
        c        a       1
        c        b       1
```

I tried to find first two columns using this code..

```
idx_cols = ['topic']
std_cols = ['student_x', 'student_y']
df1 = df.merge(df, on=idx_cols)
df2 = df1.loc[f1.student_x != f1.student_y, idx_cols + std_cols]

df2.loc[:, std_cols] = np.sort(df2.loc[:, std_cols])
```

Does anyone have some suggestions for the third column?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @blackmamba check it now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your data is already sorted by topic,student and then level. If not, please sort it first.

```
#generate the reply_count for each valid combination by comparing the current row and the row above.
count_list = df.apply(lambda x: [df.ix[x.name-1].student if x.name >0 else np.nan, x.student, x.level>1], axis=1).values

#create a count dataframe using the count_list data
df_count = pd.DataFrame(columns=['st_source','st_dest','reply_count'], data=count_list)

#Aggregate and sum all counts belonging to a source-dest pair, finally remove rows with same source and dest.
df_count = df_count.groupby(['st_source','st_dest']).sum().astype(int).reset_index()[lambda x: x.st_source != x.st_dest]

print(df_count)
Out[218]: 
  st_source st_dest  reply_count
1         a       b            4
2         b       a            2
3         b       c            1
4         c       a            1
5         c       b            1
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! @Allen

Comment: btw how can I keep also 0 rows?